# Best web front-end for SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm researching SVN repository browsers, and it's a tiresome task given how many are out there (I started [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html#browsers))

The "ideal" system would

- Run on Linux
- Be easy to use, even for non-developer types
- Look nice (have a decent skin)
- Either have built-in access control, or be written in PHP so that I could hack it myself to hook it up to something like an [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP) server.

Basically, I'm researching the idea of using a SVN front-end as also a delivery system for assets to other employees (think account executives, project managers, etc.) who need read-only access and are not as technically minded so it needs to be easy to use/navigate. And I'd really need to be able to set read permissions on a per-folder basis - we can't have everyone with full read access to the entire repository.

Comment: +1 Good question. I'm also looking around in case there's something better to replace ViewVC... maybe something like FishEye but free. :) Just curious: did any of the answers help you? Did you try e.g. Trac for this?

Answer (score 20):

Trac.( http://trac.edgewall.org/  ) Its not wonderful, but from what I've seen, for SVN its the best.

With Access control to boot.

I managed to set up a rig with even per-directory permissions for various trac users ( they just didn't  appear ) .

Been a while tho.

Default Skin looks pretty good, and is highly tunable.

Comes with a wiki & bug tracker, which you can disable if you want.

Comment: best free option (tho if you can go commercial, fisheye beats this hands down).

Answer (score 11):

Atlassian Fisheye http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/ is a commercial one that I can't live without!

(full disclosure...I am employed by Atlassian, but I say without bias that Fisheye is the best one out there that I've used)

Comment: I just wish you guys could make it more stable. It's a major memory hog and throws exceptions and crashes all the time. A little less focus on features and more on stability would get you a long way. At my last company, we fought with hosting these products constantly (although your support did work with us).

Answer (score 7):

[redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is what we're using at work.
It's similar to trac, but offers multiple project capability. The browser's decent, allowing role based permissions on each project, and each project is based on a subtree of the repository.

Also lets you browse other repository types, has a file store for publishing files and a wiki - all of which can be disabled or enabled on a per-project basis.

Comment: +1 for Redmine, it's way ahead of Trac

Answer (score 7):

[WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/)? It's written in PHP, lightweight, and simple. Check out the [demo](http://demo.websvn.info/listing.php).

Comment: I've used this too and found it very easy to use.

Comment: Fantastic little bit of software. Exactly what i needed.

Comment: WebSVN is not maintained anymore, the current project owner has switched from SVN to something else.

Comment: Websvn has new maintainers and recent development activity.

Answer (score 6):

The trunk development version (set to become version 1.1) of ViewVC supports access control. ViewVC is featureful as a repository viewer, and intuitive to use, without any unnecessary extras.

Comment: +1 for ViewVC. We looked at other free tools, like sventon and OpenGrok, but they didn't really prove to be significantly better (or even provide all the things we've used ViewVC & ViewVC query for).

Comment: ViewVC doesn't provide a diff view for a changeset, only for individual files. Also, the side-by-side comparison and difference highlighting isn't nearly as fancy as in Trac.

Answer (score 4):

[sventon](http://www.sventon.org/) looks very interesting. It is a servlet/jsp solution written on top of the svnkit Java library. It can act as a true client, so it does not need direct access the repository (like ViewVC for example). It can use the access control of the repository itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not employed by Atlassian and fisheye is great.  I think adding in crucible makes it a real win.  (in the past I have used websvn and found that to be ok).  I don't really like the viewVC interface.  There's somthing about it that makes it harder for me to groc the changes, I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

We used ViewVC for browsing both CVS and SVN repositories but since we switched to [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye) we finally have a really good solution for code browsing and examination.

We also use other Atlassian products (Jira and Confluence) and integration between all of them is just marvelous!

PS. I'm not an Atlassian employee :)

Answer (score 1):

http://beanstalkapp.com/ will host your repository and make it navigable at the same time.

Comment: http://assembla.com/ is also in this category.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at http://www.groowiki.com

We plan to have the access control features you miss, it is on the roadmap. We also target search, workflow support and right now you can add description to the file and directories
using radeox and write plugins in Java or Groovy.

And yes, I am affiliated with Groowiki. I wrote it and plan to develop it further. And it is free AND commercial as well. Only a very few features are closed (not open) source so big companies needing those specific features support its development.