# OVH : SVN http and netbeans acces

Tags: svn

I have "hébérgement mutualisé pro" with OVH, I have access SSH and I installed svn using this tutorial  http://guide.ovh.com/SVNMutu , after installation I checkout file from svn like that :

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://login@ftp.domain.com/homez.xxx/login/www/svn/depot /home
```

And it's work using ssh on Terminal,now my issue is how to do checkout using netbeans,I tried the same url and others but never work.

Firstly I try this link :

```
http://domain.com/homez.xxx/login/www/svn/depot
```

I get this error :

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: PROPFIND of '/homez.xxx/login/www/svn/depot': 405 Method Not Allowed (http://domain.com)
```

I try this url also :

```
http://login@ftp.domain.com/homez.xxx/login/www/svn/depot
```

I have the error :

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: connection refused by the server
```

OPTIONS request failed on '/homez.xxx/login/www/svn/depot'

Also I have a second issue that after creation svn on OVH server,when I access to my repository with browser I don't have an authentication svn before viewing svn files,I thinked I must put a custom configuration in vhost.conf but I guess I can't access to this file on OVH server or how,so I tried to put this line in .htaccess but it's doesn't work?

```
RewriteRule .*\.svn/.* - [F]
```

Edit:

Now the svn works fine for so I created trunk ,branches and tags forlder :

```
sudo svn add trunk svn+ssh://login@ftp.damain.com/homez.xxx/login/www/svn/depot -m "info"
```

so when I checkout my files with netbeans I have this :

- depot

  - trunk
  - branches
  - branches

Also I added a php file "index.php" in trunk for test.

But when I access to my site on browser using this link :

```
http://domain.com/svn/depot/
```

So the server don't run the php file of test on browser but I have this files :

```
 Parent Directory                             -   
      README.txt              04-Jul-2013 14:55  229   
      conf/                   04-Jul-2013 14:55    -   
      db/                     05-Jul-2013 03:14    -   
      format                  04-Jul-2013 14:55    2   
      hooks/                  04-Jul-2013 14:55    -   
      locks/                  04-Jul-2013 14:55    -
```

So I can checkout and commit to my repository but I can't see the file of test on line on browser...?

Also how I protect or I hide files for my repository?

**EDIT2:**

So Now the svn works very fine but if I make change in my project svn,how I'll chek the modification  on line on browser?!

How we will do in other remote servers,do you have tutorials to setup that?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `svn+ssh` protocol [is supported by Netbeans' svn integration](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#checking) you should be able to enter

`svn+ssh://ftp.domain.com/homez.xxx/login/www/svn/depot`

in the "repository URL" field, and the login and password in the appropriate fields in the checkout wizard.

Now, as the OVH tutorial doesn't cover access to your repo over http it probably won't work without reconfiguring the webserver.  But that's no problem, as `svn` or `svn+ssh` seem to work fine in your case.

EDIT: without going into details, based on the info you gave in the comments I think that your http server doesn't have the necessary modules on board to offer svn access via http (but check [the red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) and bounce this question back to the hoster, there may be solutions) so it's totally pointless to offer direct access to the repo via the webserver.  Maybe a web-based frontend to svn, like [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/) or [look here for some other suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95868/best-web-front-end-for-svn) could help you?  For all direct usage of the repo, as `svn+ssh` appears to work correctly and that should be sufficient to actually use the repo.

Comment: Ok for access to netbeans is working very well now,but I don't understand what you mean with ' won't work without reconfiguring the webserver' can you explain more with how to setup ovh sever for http access?

Comment: Your http server needs to be configured as explained in [the red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html), among other things WebDAV must be active.  I can't help you with that, I even have no idea whether the OVH webserver will allow you to load the proper modules, but the info in the [red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: no OVH dont offer me WebDAV,you can see please my modification above to understand my issue and you can help me if you can!tnks

Comment: In my opinion you should *not* allow access to the repo via the webserver under these circumstances - you will *not* be able to offer proper access to the repo due to lacking webdav & co support.  Just block access to the repo via http and access it via svn+ssh.  See my edit.

Comment: I think you're complicating things a lot and refuse to believe/accept that you can forget about direct browser access due to lack of the correct modules :-(  Just commit using either your local commandline svn, or Netbeans' built-in commit menu point.  Wrt different remote servers, I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just to understand,what I need is to show changes on line for client if I make modifications of code on my repository svn?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32962/discussion-between-fvu-and-nll)